# How to enable osf (old style figures) in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

So my problem is that i have font witch supports [osf](http://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/level-3/numbers/oldstyle-figures) (old style figures) but i don't know how to enable it with [UIFont](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIFont_Class/index.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured it out.

OSF is optional feature included in some fonts, so we need to activate this feature using

```
UIFontDescriptor *fontDescriptor = [UIFontDescriptor fontDescriptorWithFontAttributes:@{
                                                                                            UIFontDescriptorNameAttribute : @"MyriadPro-Light",
                                                                                            UIFontDescriptorFeatureSettingsAttribute : @[osfFontFeature]
                                                                                            }];
```

where osfFontFeature is

```
NSDictionary *osfFontFeature = @{
                                     UIFontFeatureTypeIdentifierKey : @(21),
                                     UIFontFeatureSelectorIdentifierKey : @(0)
                                     };
```

Feature type and selector identifier keys can be obtained here:
https://developer.apple.com/fonts/TrueType-Reference-Manual/RM09/AppendixF.html#Type21

Finally, we create font with

```
[UIFont fontWithDescriptor:fontDescriptor size:17.0]
```